# App Engine - URL Parameters not working with get_serving_url() in Development Server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to display images of varying dimensions using the [`google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url()` with URL parameters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url). This works fine when I deploy it to the actual app engine server. However, it doesn't work in my development server. It properly renders the entire image. However, as soon as I specify =sXX or =sXX-c, the page is blank. The log prints an error containing

```
line 379, in _OpenImageData
    images_service_pb.ImagesServiceError.NOT_IMAGE)
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 3
```

I have installed Pillow for PIL. Why is this not working?

Update: I've attempted to upload a png and a jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/images/images_stub.py#379) of the Google Images Module it seems that you may be handling an unsupported image type. The allowed types are:

```
FORMAT_LIST = [BMP, GIF, ICO, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, WEBP]
```

Comment: I'm testing with png and jpeg files.

Comment: The return value of **images.format** in images_stub.py line 376 simply isn't in the FORMAT_LIST... can you put a breakpoint there or print/log the **img_format** variable to see what's coming back?  We've run into several issues over the years where certain variations on a format will break things (like multi-layered TIFF)... perhaps your JPEG/PNG file is one of those... or perhaps it's a bug that needs to be reported

Comment: I agree with @NickFranceschina . This might be an issue with the Google Library retrieving the image format or the image file stores an "incompatible" format. On the former please file a bug on the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3)